Issue in Aws SES API Call
I am working on a Laravel project and need to use AWS SES V2. However, my AWS SDK is an older version and does not include the SES V2 client, so I decided to use the REST API instead.
I created functions to handle the necessary processes. The function for fetching the suppression list works fine, but when I use the DeleteSuppressedDestination API, I encounter the following error: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access."
This is my code
    private function getAuthorizationHeaders($method, $uri, $queryParams = '', $service = 'ses') {
        $host = "email.{$this->region}.amazonaws.com";
        $amzDate = gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z');
        $dateStamp = gmdate('Ymd');

        $canonicalUri = $uri;
        $canonicalQuerystring = $queryParams;
        $canonicalHeaders = "host:$host\nx-amz-date:$amzDate\n";
        $signedHeaders = 'host;x-amz-date';
        $payloadHash = hash('sha256', '');

        $canonicalRequest = "$method\n$canonicalUri\n$canonicalQuerystring\n$canonicalHeaders\n$signedHeaders\n$payloadHash";
        $algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
        $credentialScope = "$dateStamp/$this->region/$service/aws4_request";
        $stringToSign = "$algorithm\n$amzDate\n$credentialScope\n" . hash('sha256', $canonicalRequest);

        $kSecret = 'AWS4' . $this->secretKey;
        $kDate = hash_hmac('sha256', $dateStamp, $kSecret, true);
        $kRegion = hash_hmac('sha256', $this->region, $kDate, true);
        $kService = hash_hmac('sha256', $service, $kRegion, true);
        $kSigning = hash_hmac('sha256', 'aws4_request', $kService, true);
        $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToSign, $kSigning);

        $authorizationHeader = "$algorithm Credential={$this->accessKey}/$credentialScope, SignedHeaders=$signedHeaders, Signature=$signature";
        return [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization' => $authorizationHeader,
            'x-amz-date' => $amzDate,
        ];
    }

And this is my API function
public function removeEmailFromSesSuppression($email) { $uri = '/v2/email/suppression/addresses/' . $email; try { $response = $this->client->delete("https://email.$this->region.amazonaws.com$uri", [ 'headers' => $this->getAuthorizationHeaders("DELETE", $uri), ]);

        $responseData = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
            logInfo("Email Address : $email removed from SES suppression list");
            return ['error' => false, 'message' => "Email Address : $email removed from SES suppression list"];
        } else {
            logInfo("Email Address : $email unable to remove from SES suppression list");
            return ['error' => true, 'message' => "Email Address : $email unable to remove from SES suppression list"];
        }
    } catch (RequestException $ex) {
        $exception = $ex->getMessage();
        logInfo("There is an error during removing email from suppression list: " . $exception);
        $message = "Email Address : $email unable to remove from SES suppression list";
        if (strripos($exception, "message")) {
            $messageArr = str_split($exception, strripos($exception, "message") + 8);
            $message = end($messageArr);
            $message = str_replace('"', '', $message);
            $message = str_replace(':', '', $message);
            $message = str_replace('}', '', $message);
            $message = str_replace(']', '', $message);
        }
        return ['error' => true, 'message' => $message];
    }
}

Please provide any insights or suggestions you may have on this issue.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/create-signed-request.html says the CanonicalUri needs to be URI-encoded. You are appending $email to it, which I am guessing is not URI-encoded already?

I tried it, but I'm still not having any luck.
I did this in my header function $canonicalUri = urlencode($uri);

You can't just encode the full thing, the / need to be kept as they are. Only the individual path components between the / need URL encoding.

Nope! i did this
$encodedEmail = rawurlencode($email);
$uri = '/v2/email/suppression/addresses/' . $encodedEmail;
still no luck

You'll have to debug what you're doing there more closely then. Go through your code, and make sure you've implemented every step, as outlined in that guide. Or take inspiration from the code they provide with their PHP SDK, https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Signature/SignatureV4.php
